# Use SASS subclasses in React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

My SCSS code :

```
.motherClass {
  ...
  .subClass {
    ...
  }
}
```

My TSX code :

```
return <div className={styles.motherClass}>
  <div className={  ???  }>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to apply the `subClass` class to the child HTML element, how one would proceed ?

I have tried with

```
className="subClass"
className={styles.motherClass.subClass}
```

But none seems to work. Is there a way to do it ?

(It seems obvious, but I would like not to escape the sub class from the mother class for encapsulation reasons, so this solution is not on the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className={styles.subClass}`

When using CSS modules, each class created in CSS/SCSS file is available as a property on the exported object.

Nesting has no effect on that, it only affects resulting selectors.